# kendoAutoComplete shows [object object] when clicked on template or item

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This code return the result below in snaps.

How to populate text field with FirstName and LastName when click on template instead of `[object object]` ?

```
function forAutoComplete(FieldName){
        var autoCompleteUsers = $("#employees").kendoAutoComplete({
            minLength: 1,
            dataTextField: FieldName,

            template: '<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid DARKGRAY; padding:10px 0; clear:both;">' +
                      '<img  style="float:left; margin-right:20px;" width=\"127\" height=\"127\" src=\"<?php echo base_url() ?>/user_uploads/employee_images/${data.Photo}\" alt=\"${data.Photo}\"/>'+
                      '<div style="display: inline-block;"><p>${ data.FileNo}</p>' +
                      '<h3>${ data.FirstName } ${ data.LastName }</h3></div>'+
                      '<div style="clear: both; "></div></div>',

            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/hr_management/manage_hr/search_employee/",
                        data: function (arg){
                            return {FieldName : autoCompleteUsers.data("kendoAutoComplete").value()};
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            height: 300,
            change: onChangeAutoComplete
        });
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely to be related with the value that you set for `dataTextField`.

Doing some-sort-of-reverse-engineering, I guess that the JSON data that you return is something like:

```
[
    {data: { FileNo: "0001", FirstName: "OnaBai", LastName: "it's me", Photo: "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2648375258/7f7e451f0de1eb467fe35f4f481d7bf7_bigger.jpeg" } },
    {data: { FileNo: "0002", FirstName: "Burke", LastName: "Holland", Photo: "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3342899483/51e933d69222ce8ad8cd14e655116959.jpeg" } },
    {data: { FileNo: "0003", FirstName: "Todd", LastName: "Anglin", Photo: "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1478082886/todd-anglin-close-up_illustrated.png" } }
]
```

If so, you should be defining it as `data.FirstName`.

If you are defining it as:

```
[
    { FileNo: "0001", FirstName: "OnaBai", LastName: "it's me", Photo: "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2648375258/7f7e451f0de1eb467fe35f4f481d7bf7_bigger.jpeg" },
    { FileNo: "0002", FirstName: "Burke", LastName: "Holland", Photo: "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3342899483/51e933d69222ce8ad8cd14e655116959.jpeg" },
    { FileNo: "0003", FirstName: "Todd", LastName: "Anglin", Photo: "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1478082886/todd-anglin-close-up_illustrated.png" }
]
```

Then it should be just `FirstName`.

Example of the first approach in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XzR7p/6/) while second in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XzR7p/)

If you define `dataTextField: "data",` and use the first approach for your JSON then you get the `[object Object]`. See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XzR7p/3/)